# que hace este algoritmo?

Tags: algoritmos, estructuras-de-datos

estoy empezando a estudiar algoritmos y estructuras y me enviaron este archivo para que lo revise e intente entenderlo, la verdad es que como apenas empiezo no comprendo bien, me pueden explicar que hace y que tipo de estructura de datos usa?
................
................
...............
.................
..............
..............................
................
.............................
................
.............................
................
...............
.................
.................
.................
...............
...............................
................
...............
.................

```
    package proyectomochilarecursivo;


public class ProyectoMochilaRecursivo {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Elemento[] elementos = {
            new Elemento(1, 1),
            new Elemento(2, 14),
            new Elemento(3, 3),
            new Elemento(4, 12),
            new Elemento(5, 2),
            new Elemento(6, 30),
            new Elemento(15, 500)
        };
        Mochila m_base = new Mochila(15, elementos.length);
        Mochila m_opt = new Mochila(15, elementos.length);

        llenarMochila(m_base, elementos, m_opt, false);
        System.out.println(m_opt);
    }

    public static void llenarMochila(Mochila m_base, Elemento[] elementos, Mochila m_opt, boolean llena) {
        if (llena) {
            if (m_base.getValor() > m_opt.getValor()) {
                Elemento[] elementoMochase = m_base.getElementos();
                m_opt.clear();
                for (Elemento e : elementoMochase) {
                    if (e != null) {
                        m_opt.AñadirtElemento(e);
                    }

                }
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
                if (!m_base.existeElemento(elementos[i])) {
                    if (m_base.getPesoMximo() >= m_base.getPeso() + elementos[i].getPeso()) {
                        m_base.AñadirtElemento(elementos[i]);
                        llenarMochila(m_base, elementos, m_opt, false);
                        m_base.eliminarElemento(elementos[i]);
                    } else {
                        llenarMochila(m_base, elementos, m_opt, true);

                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, Entiendes algunas partes de este programa?, serìa bueno agregaras que parte entiendes en tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: tengo la idea de que ordena según el peso y precio y elimina los menos pesados y costosos, pero ni idea, como he dicho apenas estoy empezando a estudiar algoritmos y estructuras

Comment: Te recomiendo que la parte que no entiendas de tu codigo, la agregues en la pregunta, pero ojo, hazlo por separado. Luego en otra pregunta puedes añadir otro pedazo de código indicando en detalle cual es tu duda y con respecto a que tipo de estructura de datos está usando el programa, básicamente es un arreglo de objetos que equivale a un arreglo de punteros (cada puntero apunta a la dirección base de un objeto).

Comment: Creo q debería desglosar el código. Por ejemplo, sabes que es una clase, que es una variable, cuales son los tipos de variables, que diferencia hay entre un método y una función, que son instancias, que es un constructor, sabes ejecutarlo, etc??

Comment: pues como ya he estudiado java, ya entiendo todos esos conceptos, el problema es que no se como usar estructuras de datos, y bueno específicamente no entiendo que hace la función llenar mochila, ni por que al ejecutar solo imprime 15 y 500